What are the electrical properties and connectors of a CW key?
I'm working on a simple homebrew design and want to connect a CW key to it. (The basic design can use a simple built in pushbutton key, but I'd like to be able to purchase a proper key and use it as well.)
What are the electrical properties and connectors of a CW key?
Is a key simply a normally open SPST push button switch?
Does one end need to be connected to ground? (I believe that is the common usage - is that a requirement for any reason?)
What type of connector or jack do keys normally require?

If you are using a microswithc/limit switch or something for a key, I find about 0.2 to 0.3N (20 to 30 gf) is most comfortable.

There are some vintage keys like US Navy Flameproof or Nye Viking Master where the lines from the key connector are not exposed to the user by entirely enclosing the contact and wiring inside. Those keys also have large contact areas, which is useful in minimizing the contact bounces and giving the contact a fairly large current capacity. Those keys would be safe to use with vintage vacuum tube transmitters. But those features are not common in currently made keys.


Is a key simply a normally open SPST push button switch?

Yes - if you're thinking of a simple hand-operated key.

Does one end need to be connected to ground? (I believe that is the common usage - is that a requirement for any reason?)

Generally, that is so. The fixed frame of a hand key is very often electrically connected to one of the two SPST wires: since the frame is accessible to your hand and to other electrical items at your operating position, it should be at a low potential voltage. Consider what might be shorted out if the key's frame were to touch other items. And consider if there's a current path through you to earth if your hand or finger(s) touch the key's frame.

What type of connector or jack do keys normally require?


Old, old school: 1/4" (6.35mm) mono phono jack.
New(er) school: headphone-style 3.5mm phono jack.

Most common 3.5mm phono jacks are stereo, with tip and ring and GND shell, but you can still get 3.5mm mono jacks and plugs. The common wiring is the "hot" side to tip, and the "cold" side (key frame) to GND shell. You can leave ring open-circuit.

"And consider if there's a current path through you to earth if your hand or finger(s) touch the key's frame." That raises an important point - what about accidental contact between the operator's hand and the hot (tip) side? Esp. with homebrew, wires can come loose - how do we keep they key safe?

OP doesn't mention what type of active devices the transmitter uses, but regardless if it's 12V, TTL or even vacuum tube, the circuit should be designed so that the voltage required to key should be small.  Even in my novice days using a tube rig (Drake TR-4 and Heathkit HW-16), there was never a risk of shock from the key.

And it will be designed that, no matter the voltage, the current capacity of the voltage source is low – you don't want to, nor gain anything by, putting an ampere of current through a little contact (aside from contact corrosion, you can gain a lot of that). So, even if your body shorts these potentials, and even if your body was as low-impedance as a closed key, you should not be carrying damaging amounts of current.
